# (unittest) Testing Flask-Security: Cannot get past login page

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest, flask-login, flask-security

I'm trying to add tests to my basic app. Accessing everything requires login.

Here's my test case class:

```
class MyAppTestCase(FlaskTestCaseMixin):

    def _create_app(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def _create_fixtures(self):
        self.user = EmployeeFactory()

    def setUp(self):
        super(MyAppTestCase, self).setUp()
        self.app = self._create_app()
        self.client = self.app.test_client()
        self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()
        db.create_all()
        self._create_fixtures()
        self._create_csrf_token()

    def tearDown(self):
        super(MyAppTestCase, self).tearDown()
        db.drop_all()
        self.app_context.pop()

    def _post(self, route, data=None, content_type=None, follow_redirects=True, headers=None):
        content_type = content_type or 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        return self.client.post(route, data=data, follow_redirects=follow_redirects, content_type=content_type, headers=headers)

    def _login(self, email=None, password=None):
        email = email or self.user.email
        password = password or 'password'
        data = {
            'email': email,
            'password': password,
            'remember': 'y'
            }
        return self._post('/login', data=data)


class MyFrontendTestCase(MyAppTestCase):

    def _create_app(self):
        return create_app(settings)

    def setUp(self):
        super(MyFrontendTestCase, self).setUp()
        self._login()
```

I am running my tests use nosetests in Terminal like so: `source my_env/bin/activate && nosetests --exe`

Basic tests like these fail:

```
class CoolTestCase(MyFrontendTestCase):

    def test_logged_in(self):
        r = self._login()
        self.assertIn('MyAppName', r.data)

    def test_authenticated_access(self):
        r = self.get('/myroute/')
        self.assertIn('MyAppName', r.data)
```

From the output, I see that `r.data` is just the HTML of the login page with no errors (e.g., wrong username or password) or alerts ("Please log in to access this page").

I am logging in during the `setUp` process, so `test_authenticated_access` *should have* let me either access `/myroute/` or redirect me to the login page with the flashed message "Please log in to access this page". But it didn't.

I can't figure out what's wrong. I based my test off of ones I found in Flask documentation and [this app boilerplate](https://github.com/mattupstate/overholt)

Comment: I see you're using CSRF tokens - have you tried disabling them and seeing if that gets you farther? I know they've bitten me in tests more times than I can remember.

Comment: If you're using (or can use) Flask 0.10, I highly recommend just using the new fake context stuff: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/#faking-resources-and-context  We're currently doing something very similar to what you're doing for our tests, and as soon as we can upgrade, I'm ripping it all out in favor of this.

Comment: @RachelSanders - I already have `WTF_CSRF_ENABLED` set to `False`

Comment: @RachelSanders - I just tried using the fake context and using the Flask-Login function `login_user`. Now it's showing the flashed message "You do not have permission to view this resource." So something changed, but the login still did not work.

Comment: The behavior that you describe fits the CSRF problem @RachelSanders mentions. Make sure your `create_app()` is using your testing configuration. Or print `app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED']` to make sure this setting is active in your app.

Comment: @Miguel - I double checked with `print self.app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED']` in my code, and it does say `False`.

Comment: Probably the server is redirecting you to the LogIn page and given you  specified follow_redirects=true you don't get a 302. Set the flag to false and verify the Status Code and Location header, it should be a 302. Anyway, I think it has nothing to do with your tests but with your web app instead.

Comment: @lontivero - I tried disabled redirects as you said, but now the result is just a "Redirecting..." page. I assume this is because I am trying to access a page with `@login_required`, so it is trying to redirect me to the login page. The app works correctly in the browser, just not in the tests.

Comment: It also appears that `current_user` is being reported as `flask_security.core.AnonymousUser`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out after a week of killing myself...

There were several problems:

1. **There is some conflict between Flask-Security and Flask-SSLify.** Although the automatic https redirection works fine on the actual web server, in the tests it prevent logging in completely. I figured this out by making fake test routes and trying to `POST` random data. No `POST` in the test client worked. To fix this, I had to change my test config `DEBUG` to `True`. Note that this is not a great workaround, since stuff like CSS and JS won't be compiled and other app behavior might be different...
2. **Flask-Security does not work with factory_boy(or I was not using factory_boy correctly?).** I was trying to create users and roles through factory_boy because I saw some sample app tutorial that used it. After I fixed the above problem, it kept telling me that the user did not exist. I ended up stealing the code from Flask-Security's own tests for creating fake users with different roles.

The problematic code:

```
session = db.create_scoped_session()

class RoleFactory(SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = Role
    FACTORY_SESSION = session

    id = Sequence(int)
    name = 'admin'
    description = 'Administrator'


class EmployeeFactory(SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = Employee
    FACTORY_SESSION = session

    id = Sequence(int)
    email = Sequence(lambda n: 'user{0}@app.com'.format(n))
    password = LazyAttribute(lambda a: encrypt_password('password'))
    username = Sequence(lambda n: 'user{0}'.format(n))
    #last_login_at = datetime.utcnow()
    #current_login_at = datetime.utcnow()
    last_login_ip = '127.0.0.1'
    current_login_ip = '127.0.0.1'
    login_count = 1
    roles = LazyAttribute(lambda _: [RoleFactory()])
    active = True
```

This was my test case:

```
class MyAppTestCase(FlaskTestCaseMixin, MyTestCase):

    def _create_app(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def _create_fixtures(self):
        #self.user = EmployeeFactory()
        populate_data(1)

    def setUp(self):
        super(MyAppTestCase, self).setUp()
        self.app = self._create_app()
        self.client = self.app.test_client()
        self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()
        db.create_all()
        self._create_fixtures()
        self._create_csrf_token()

    def tearDown(self):
        super(MyAppTestCase, self).tearDown()
        db.drop_all()
        self.app_context.pop()

    def _post(self, route, data=None, content_type=None, follow_redirects=True, headers=None):
        content_type = content_type or 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        return self.client.post(route, data=data, follow_redirects=follow_redirects, content_type=content_type, headers=headers)

    def _login(self, email=None, password=None):
        email = email or 'matt@lp.com' #self.user.email
        password = password or 'password'
        data = {
            'email': email,
            'password': password,
            'remember': 'y'
            }
        return self._post('/login', data=data)
```

Comment: you listed the problem test, but not the working test.  Could not easily find it here. https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with login/logout on tests with Flask-Security (that uses Flask-Login) app also. I solved this problem by mocking `flask_login._get_user` function and setting `app.login_manager._login_disabled` to True.

Context manager that mocks user:

```
class LoginLogoutMixin(object):
    @contextmanager
    def login(self, user):
        mock_get_user = patch('flask_login._get_user', Mock(return_value=user))
        self.app.login_manager._login_disabled = True
        mock_get_user.start()
        yield
        mock_get_user.stop()
        self.app.login_manager._login_disabled = False
```

And an example of it's usage:

```
class ProtectedViewTestCase(LoginLogoutMixin, TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        super(ProtectedViewTestCase, self).setUp()
        # create user here

    def test_protected_view(self):
        with self.login(self.user):
            rv = self.client.get(url_for('protected_view'))
            self.assert200(rv)
```